# Prevent events to be triggered unecessarily

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function(){
     $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
});

$('#menu > li').mouseleave(function(){

     $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
});
```

this works fine, but if i hover/leave an `<li>` item of the menu many times and very fast, once i stop i will see it slide up and down as many times as i hovered,

please watch this sort video capture

http://www.screenr.com/dkes

¿how can that be prevent?

Comment: would you mind using simple CSS for this?

Comment: no i am afraid i need it to be js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the current animation. You could also combine your two event handlers and just use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) (which can take 2 arguments, the first is a function to run on `mouseenter`, the second a function to run on `mouseleave`):

```
$('#menu > li').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp();
});
```

The first argument is `clearQueue`, which will stop the animations queueing up endlessly as you hover repeatedly. The second argument is `jumpToEnd`, which forces any currently running animation to end before starting a new one.

Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/DteZm/).

Answer (score 0):

It all boils down to you having a variable that will store the state of your sliding and will prevent further requests from happening if a sliding is already taking place.

Set the flag at the beginning of sliding and use callback to unset the flag.

```
var closing = false;
$('#menu > li').mouseleave(function(){
     closing = true;
     $(this).find('ul').slideUp(null, function(){
         closing = false;
     });
});

// then in the hover method you would just check the value of closing to see if to allow or not opening.
```

The second idea was exposed a little earlier by James Allardice, and I like it more if it works.